# WiX: Installer always changes AppPool to enable 32bit app

Tags: iis, web-applications, wix, pool

WiX installer installs silverlight web application. It can work under 32 or 64 bit app pool. But when installation completed  I see that selected app pool always set to Enable 32-bit applications.It is even for 64-bit pools. It is not sutiable because it can change existing pool for previously installed 64 applications. 
I do not change explicitely this parameter. What is the reason of problem may be?

The code sample added:

```
<Component Id="WebAppVDirComponent"
    Guid="C7A4B0E8-2389-4A2A-B285-96960BEE1C52" KeyPath="yes">
    <Condition><![CDATA[RBGROUP_HOSTING = "iis"]]></Condition>
        <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="VDir"
                Alias="[WEB_APP_NAME]"
                Directory="INSTALLDIR"
                WebSite="TheWebSite" >
        <iis:MimeMap Id="SilverlightMimeType" Extension=".xap" Type="application/x-silverlight-app" />
        <iis:WebApplication Id="WorkWebApplication"
                Name="[WEB_APP_NAME]" WebAppPool="TheAppPool"/>
        </iis:WebVirtualDir>
        <iis:WebAppPool Id="TheAppPool" Name="[APP_POOL_NAME]" ></iis:WebAppPool>           
        <CreateFolder/>
</Component>
```

Answer (score 19):

This had been designed in a very elegant way, in my opinion.

If you place the `<iis:WebAppPool>` element declaration to the `<Component>` marked as `Win64="yes"`, the application pool will be created with `Enable32bit` flag set to `false`. Otherwise (that is, by default), it will be created with `Enable32bit` set to `true`.

I'm not sure how it will behave when you don't create the application pool with your installation, but reference the existing one instead. I would expect it not to change this flag at all. You can experiment with this to find out how it works exactly.

And a side note: I would avoid installing to the existing application pool or website. This is far more difficult to maintain - remember that you must leave the machine in its "pre-install" state after uninstallation. This means you'll have to maintain backup/restore the state of everything you change with custom actions... Brrr...

Comment: Thank you , Yan. Hmm....yes, its interesting... I have added the code which I use.

Comment: So, the code you added will create app pool with Enable32bit set to 'true'. You might want to add another component with opposite condition, that is, using VersionNT64 and Win64 attribute set to yes, and add all the same stuff to it.

Comment: Yes, when I create a new pool no problem. But the problem is when user selects the existing one (64-bit) and this pool then changed to 32-bit. I use custom .NET functions to select pool.

Comment: How do you handle the error when its asking you to change your directory to a 64 bit directory as I have to bind the component to a directory for anything to work.

Comment: I think this error you mention occurs when there is analogue 32-bit directory, right? I haven't seen it personally, to be honest, but I suspect if the directory is under wwwroot the error won't occur...

Comment: For future readers: I was able to get it to work with (this hint)
Win64="yes" in the component (xml-tag) that wraps the iis:WebAppPool xml .... BUT ALSO ..... I had to  add Platform="x64"  in the Package (xml-tag) 

I'll put the xml below.  Not sure if it'll post as a comment.

    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Platform="x64" />

and

      <Component Id="MyAppPool.Component" Guid="" KeyPath="yes" Win64="yes">

        <iis:WebAppPool (blah blah blah)
      </Component>